# Postgresql create function index on dynamic values

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have such a query

```
select r.timestamp, r,value
   from result_table r
  where timestamp > ( NOW() - INTERVAL '120 hour' )
    and r.id%10=1`
```

where `id` is the autoincremental primary key.

Instead, 120 and 10 can by any other number (decided by the user depending on his needs). Basically, the user wants data for some time interval with some decimation.

Obviously, it works too slow on a big amount of data. What should be the index(s) here?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL supports SQL expression or function indexes

```
  where
    timestamp > ( NOW() - INTERVAL '120 hour' )
    and r.id % 10 = 1
```

Needs the index `(timestamp, (id % 10))` to get more performance.

**Query**

```
CREATE INDEX
 timestamp__idmod10
ON 
 result_table
(timestamp, (id % 10))
```

see demos

with index      http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8e63b/6  
without index   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9be99/3

**Editted because of comment**

> Thanks, Raymond, However, (id % 10) is not that good since instead of
>   10 can be any other number. 9, 11, 100, 1, etc

Other approach use `generate_series()` and a delivered table to generate a id list matching % number = 1. 
And use that resultset with a IN clause.

p.s this statement assumes a id column with SERIAL and a table equal or less then 1 million records. Also keep in mind that the `generate_series()` function takes some time.

**SQL statement**

```
 SELECT 
   numbers.number FROM (  
      SELECT
        generate_series(1, 1000000) as number
      ) AS numbers 
    WHERE
      numbers.number % number = 1
```

Then you can use the index

```
CREATE INDEX timestamp_id ON result_table(timestamp, id);
```

And the query

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 result_table 
WHERE
   timestamp > ( NOW() - INTERVAL '120 hour' ) 
 AND
   id IN (

     SELECT 
       numbers.number FROM (  
          SELECT
            generate_series(1, 1000000) as number
          ) AS numbers 
        WHERE
          numbers.number % 10 = 1

   )
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5013c0/6 with example data.

Comment: Thanks, Raymond,
However, (id % 10) is not that good since instead of 10 can be any other number. 9, 11, 100, 1, etc

Comment: Posted a other approch @АзаматСиражитдинов